# Javadoc {@inheritDoc} tag class

Tags: java, javadoc, inheritdoc

I would like to use the `{@inheritDoc}` class to inherit methods from my abstract class.  In the documentation for the abstract class, I refer to the abstract class by name.  How can I tag this so when the subclass inherits the documentation from the super class, it replaces the abstract class's name with the subclass's name?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

What you are describing is not supported by the javadoc generation tool.

And I think that there is a **good reason** for this too:

If your method in the subclass is merely an implementation of an abstract method, then I think it would be correct to leave the abstract class' name in there.

On the flip side, if your method in the subclass is not just a simple implementation, and does something more that is noteworthy (enough to be mentioned in the javadoc), then you should write a new javadoc on the method in the subclass, instead of invoking inheritDoc.

Comment: My reasoning behind this was the reader of my code wouldn't normally look at the abstract class behind the implementation, so I wanted to hide it.  However, it appears I can't do this.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: If the user of your class needs the documentation for the method, but they should not know about the existence of the abstract base class, then the method definition should be moved to an interface, along with the javadoc that's on the abstract class. In essence, the interface is what the user will case about. Both points in the answer above would still apply.

Answer (score 18):

I'm not aware of a way, but you might elaborate on why you want [`{@inheritDoc}`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/javadoc/doc-comment-spec.html#inheritdoc) to do this. I may misunderstand, but it seems confusing. You can document how your concrete implementation varies form the parent and use [`@see`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/javadoc/doc-comment-spec.html#see) to refer to the contract in the abstract class. Note ["*Method Comment Inheritance*"](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/javadoc/doc-comment-spec.html#method-comment-inheritance) may obviate the need for an explicit [`{@inheritDoc}`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/javadoc/doc-comment-spec.html#inheritdoc).

Answer (score 1):

You can also, IIRC, write additional text around the `{@inheritDoc}` tag in your own comments.